# "Leftover" color on CSS hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have never seen anything like this before, so not even sure how to phrase the question. I'm using a standard CSS :hover effect to change the color of some links on my page. However, when using webkit, only the bottom 95% of the text changes color, the top stays it's original color. It is happening for most links on the page. Firefox looks fine, Chrome and Safari both have the problem.

It is a Rails site using Foundation 5, but that shouldn't matter, I don't think.

Any thoughts?

**Normal text link**

[image: Normal text link]

**Hover text link**

[image: Hover text link]

--edit it's just bog standard CSS

```
a{color:#559ada;text-decoration:none;line-height:inherit}
a:hover,a:focus{color:#3285d2}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: If it's, just CSS it's clearly a rendering issue, you could try to set line-height higher, but I don't think there is a general fix for that.

Comment: That's not enough of the code since it doesn't allow is to reproduce the problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rjv5wp93/

Comment: Post HTML too. We can't help much unless we truly understand the structure of your webpage.

Comment: Not to mention that the images show a blue and an orange, and the hex codes are for two different blues. Strange.

Comment: Yes yes, wrong hex codes, regardless it's still just a standard CSS hover, nothing fancy going on. I figured out it is a bug with how webkit renders this particular google webfont. I have tried approx 20 other fonts and they all work as expected. Not sure still what is going on here, but it appears to be some unique combination of webkit and this webfont (Cutive from Google Web Fonts)